# HttpListener: how to get http user and password?

Tags: c#, passwords, httplistener

I'm facing a problem here, with HttpListener.

When a request of the form

```
http://user:password@example.com/
```

is made, how can I get the user and password ?
HttpWebRequest has a Credentials property, but HttpListenerRequest doesn't have it, and I didn't find the username in any property of it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you're attempting to do is pass credentials via HTTP basic auth, I'm not sure if the username:password syntax is supported in HttpListener, but if it is, you'll need to specify that you accept basic auth first.

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add(uriPrefix);
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
listener.Start();
```

Once you receive a request, you can then extract the username and password with:

```
HttpListenerBasicIdentity identity = (HttpListenerBasicIdentity)context.User.Identity;
Console.WriteLine(identity.Name);
Console.WriteLine(identity.Password);
```

[Here's a full explanation](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/prev/v2/documentation/authentication/httplistener_auth) of all supported authenitcation methods that can be used with HttpListener.

Comment: Sorry, I said "I'm not if the username:password syntax is supported in HttpListener", but of course it's the client that will convert this into a "WWW-Authenticate: basic" header, so it only matters if the client supports it. I believe support for it has been dropped from IE recently.

Answer (score 5):

Get the `Authorization` header. It's format is as follows

```
Authorization: <Type> <Base64-encoded-Username/Password-Pair>
```

Example:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

The username and password is colon-seperated (in this example, `Aladdin:open sesame`), then B64-encoded.

Answer (score 5):

You need to first enable Basic Authentication:

```
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
```

Then in your ProcessRequest method you could get username and password:

```
if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var identity = (HttpListenerBasicIdentity)context.User.Identity;
    Console.WriteLine(identity.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(identity.Password);
}
```