# how to get active user from ip address in same network

Tags: c#, ldap, windows-server-2008, ldap-query

I have network IP address can I know the active user based on the particular IP address

I have under details of the same network

```
        "host"+"-" + new Program().GetHostName(ip[0].ToString()).ToString() + "<br>" +
    "KeepAlive" + request.KeepAlive + "<br>" +
    "Local end point: {0}" + "-" + request.LocalEndPoint.ToString() + "<br>" +
    "Remote end point: {0}" + "-" + "--" + "<br>" +
    "Is local? {0}" + "-" + request.IsLocal + "<br>" +
    "HTTP method: {0}" + "-" + request.HttpMethod + "<br>" +
    "Protocol version: {0}" + "-" + request.ProtocolVersion + "<br>" +
    "Is authenticated: {0}" + "-" + request.IsAuthenticated + "<br>" +
    "Is secure: {0}" + "<br>" + request.IsSecureConnection + "<br>" +
    //"username " + "-"+ username + "<br>"+
```

Comment: it is c# console application which has an HTTP listener,yes i want currently active user

Comment: What data do you have available to link username/IP? Even on the same network, if you don't have admin rights on another machine (either via user/password, or domain rights) you shouldn't be able to find the logged in user's username, if that's what you mean.

Comment: this application runs on a windows server which has the active directive

Comment: In that case, perhaps [this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212155/how-to-get-logged-on-users-with-their-status-on-remote-machine)?

Comment: it's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using an HttpListener/HttpRequestListener here, and if so please see [HttpListener: how to get http user and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147308/httplistener-how-to-get-http-user-and-password) - the accepted answer there deals with basic auth but it links to an article that details how to request Windows auth, so the client should quote the logged in windows user name to your app.

Ps: Looks like you're creating a log? That string concat code is a bit of a mess and would benefit from being tidied up, maybe using interpolated strings:

```
    $@"Host: {new Program().GetHostName(ip[0].ToString())}<br/>
KeepAlive: {request.KeepAlive}<br/>
Local end point: {request.LocalEndPoint}<br/>
... and so on ...
```